# How to fix a .bashrc that's been edited wrongly?

Tags: linux

I had edited the `bashrc` file wrongly in my Ubuntu, while trying to put an `"export"` command in `bashrc` for `javac`.

When I type `sudo`, it's saying:

> Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo' 
>   The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment >variable. sudo: command not found

How should I correct this?

Comment: This question is more suited to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restore your `.bashrc` with the following command:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

If you want to see the differences between your customized `.bashrc` and the default one, use this (no changes are made):

```
diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely stomped on your existing PATH variable. Make sure that if you export PATH, include the existing PATH, too:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/whatever/you/added
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just type the full path to sudo:

```
/usr/bin/sudo vim /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: @subhransu: If you did actually edit your system-wide bashrc, I suggest you revert those edits and edit your personal `~/.bashrc` instead.