# Restoring ~/.bashrc without using bash commands

Tags: linux, bashrc

I think I had a typo when I add a path to `~/.bashrc` and after I source it, I cannot use bash commands anymore.

Now I want to restore a normal `~/.bashrc`, however most of the discussion I found (e.g. [How to fix a .bashrc that's been edited wrongly?](https://superuser.com/questions/191022/how-to-fix-a-bashrc-thats-been-edited-wrongly?newreg=27237e4b3487495a83625188505a3209)) needs to use bash commands e.g. `cp`

```
clam@cuerei:~# cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
cp: /home/cltam/script/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by cp)
```

May I know how could I restore `~/.bashrc` without using bash commands?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed @Peter Cordes suggestion to undo my edit by: unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 25):

`cp` is not a bash command – it's an external program. This is why it fails; actual bash commands would be unaffected by library or path changes. So you want the opposite, i.e. using *only* bash commands.

You could delete the file's contents completely, using:

```
true > ~/.bashrc
```

Or overwrite with some other contents:

```
echo "" > ~/.bashrc
```

Or you could try to temporarily undo the bad changes within the live shell:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_PRELOAD LD_AUDIT
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Or you could copy the file's contents, line by line, using just shell built-ins:

```
while IFS="" read -r line; do
    echo "$line";
done < /etc/skel/.bashrc > ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Surely I'm not the only one who keeps staticly linked copies of critical binaries lying around.

Comment: Or a live USB to boot from

Comment: in a locked low-humidity temperature-controlled vault accessible only when two keys are turned simultaneously in locks that are eight feet apart .... whups, sorry.

Comment: Or more simply, just `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and use `vim` or whatever to fix the typo in your existing `.bashrc`, then re-source it.  No need to wipe it out.

Comment: @PeterCordes Or even `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= vim ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Oh, also, in BASH you can copy the whole file with `echo "$(</etc/skel/.bashrc)" > ~/.bashrc` or a safer `printf '%s'` equivalent, because it's small enough to easily fit in memory.  `$(<filename)` works like `cat` but without actually forking + execing an external process, just making bash read the file.  The `while read` loop is not necessary for small files.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Any `$()` will still cause bash to fork internally (even the variants which have nothing to exec), and I've been in situations where even that failed for various reasons.

Comment: @user1686: interesting.  Fortunately on the OP's system, only execve was broken because of a bad environment var.  But in general for broken systems, if you can unbreak them by changing an env var, do that instead.  So if you're going to manually copy, avoiding fork seems good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently logged into the system?
If so, you can switch to another shell, then edit the file

```
> chsh
> vi ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If `cp` won't run, what makes you think `chsh` will run?

Answer (score 1):

You broke your library path which is used for dynamically linked programs.  Those do not contain all the code needed to execute the program, but load some from shared libraries at start up time.

Some programs are compiled to avoid this issue (for instance for programs running as root or needed very early in the boot process).  They are traditionally placed in `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`.   What exactly is there depends on what is installed.

On my Mac it does not appear that there is an editor available, but your system might have.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. when I use
`/usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc`
I can edit .bashrc again